# Project Euler problem 26 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

Question statement:

> A unit fraction contains 1 in the numerator. The decimal representation of the unit fractions with denominators 2 to 10 are given:
>
> ```
> 1/2   =   0.5
> 1/3   =   0.(3)
> 1/4   =   0.25
> 1/5   =   0.2
> 1/6   =   0.1(6)
> 1/7   =   0.(142857)
> 1/8   =   0.125
> 1/9   =   0.(1)
> 1/10  =   0.1
> ```
>
> Where 0.1(6) means 0.166666..., and has a 1-digit recurring cycle. It can be seen that 1/7 has a 6-digit recurring cycle.
>
> Find the value of d < 1000 for which 1/d contains the longest recurring cycle in its decimal fraction part.

Link: https://projecteuler.net/problem=26

I tried to solve it in **Python**:

My approach:

- For every d, assume you are solving for `1 / d` by hand.
- In case the 1 is completely divisible by d, it means the cycle length is 0.
- If a value you have already divided appears again, it means you've found the cycle.
- The cycle would have length of the number of times you've repeated the first step minus the first time the cycled value appears as we have to remove non-cycling values.

Here's my code following the above steps in **Python**:

```py
LIMIT = 1000

# The maximum length
maxi = 0

# The 'd' that has maximum length
maxi_d = 1

for d in range(1, LIMIT):
    quotient = [] # Stores the decimal quotient
    cur_value = 1 # Variable used to perform division as if by hand

    len_recur = 0 # Recurring length

    # Performing division as if by hand.
    while cur_value not in quotient:
        if not cur_value:   # If the value is not recurring:
            break           # break as the rucurring length must be 0

        len_recur += 1
        quotient.append(cur_value)

        cur_value = (cur_value % d) * 10

    if not cur_value:
        continue

    # Remove number of values that do not recur
    len_recur -= quotient.index(cur_value) + 1

    if len_recur > maxi:
        maxi = len_recur
        maxi_d = d

print(maxi_d)
```

I'd like to make this code as fast as possible. This currently takes ~3.5 seconds for `LIMIT = 2000` and grows exponentially larger.

PS: I know `len_recur` can be replaced by `len(quotient)`, but I want the code to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Boosting time performance:*

Starting with minor naming issues:
`maxi` is better named as **`max_len`** (as stated in comment). `maxi_d` is renamed to **`max_d`**.
It's good to move the processing into a separate function, called like **`calc_longest_recur_cycle`**.

The main *time-performance* hits in your implementation is caused by **`quotient`** list and its expensive *list* operations:

- `quotient.append`
- `quotient.index`
- `cur_value not in quotient`

According to that fact that `quotient` and `len_recur` are reset on each outer `for` loop iteration and on the level of `while` loop the fragment

```
len_recur += 1
quotient.append(cur_value)
```

tells that `cur_value` is appended synchronously with incrementing `len_recur` i.e. the `cur_value` will get the position equal to `len_recur`. That means that, on this level, `cur_value` can be **mapped** to its position contained in `len_recur`.
Thus, `quotient` is initiated as dictionary (instead of list): **`quotient = {}`** or even **`quotient = {0: 0}`** as [`AJNeufeld`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100620/ajneufeld) suggested to eliminate `cur_value` evaluation on the `while` loop condition.

---

The construction:

```
while cur_value not in quotient:
    if not cur_value:  # If the value is not recurring:
        break
```

is essentially a verbose equivalent to:

```
while cur_value and cur_value not in quotient:
```

---

*List* indexing

```
len_recur -= quotient.index(cur_value) + 1
```

is now efficiently replaced with *dict* indexing (where values are *positions*)

```
len_recur -= quotient[cur_value]
```

---

Now, with `quotient` as `dict`, we have ***O(1)*** complexity for *membership check* (`cur_value not in quotient`) and *indexing* operation (`len_recur -= quotient[cur_value]`)

The final version:

```
LIMIT = 5000

def calc_longest_recur_cycle():
    max_len = 0   # The maximum length
    max_d = 1     # The 'd' that has maximum length

    for d in range(1, LIMIT):
        quotient = {0: 0}  # Stores the decimal quotient
        cur_value = 1      # Variable used to perform division as if by hand
        len_recur = 0      # Recurring length

        # Performing division as if by hand
        while cur_value not in quotient:  # while the value is not recurring
            len_recur += 1
            quotient[cur_value] = len_recur
            cur_value = (cur_value % d) * 10

        if not cur_value:
            continue

        # Remove number of values that do not recur
        len_recur -= quotient[cur_value]
        # quotient.clear()

        if len_recur > max_len:
            max_len = len_recur
            max_d = d

    return max_d
```

---

What needs to be mentioned is that despite of its *fast nature* `dict` would take more space than `list`, but only at the time of one nominal loop iteration as it's reset and last `quotient` filled at the end will be garbage-collected on function exit.

Let's get to tests.
I've increased limit to **`LIMIT = 5000`** to *"turn up the heat"* and have put the "old" implementation into separate function `calc_recur_cycle_old` for comparison.
As for resulting `max_d` value - both functions return the same result:

```
print(calc_recur_cycle_old())      # 4967
print(calc_longest_recur_cycle())  # 4967
```

And the most interesting *time performance* comparison:

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('calc_recur_cycle_old()', 'from __main__ import calc_recur_cycle_old', number=1))
19.648109548998036

print(timeit('calc_longest_recur_cycle()', 'from __main__ import calc_longest_recur_cycle', number=1))
0.26926991600339534
```

The end ... )

Comment: You should initialize `quotient = {0: 0}`,  then the loop condition could simplify to `while cur_value not in quotient:`, which should execute slightly faster.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, that gained only `0.02` sec, but also a good micro-improvement. Thanks, mentioned you in the answer description